# Erro ao compilar código no eclipse

Tags: java

Estou com um pequeno problema ao compilar esse código, depois que eu compilo aparece o seguinte erro:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   10

Eu pesquisei em outros locais, e disseram que esse erro ocorre quando você está ultrapassando o tamanho de um vetor, mas não entendi o que está errado no meu código.

```
public class Questao5Agenda {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner inputNumerico = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner inputString = new Scanner(System.in);


        Contato [] c1 = new Contato[10];
        int opc;


        do{

             c1[10].Menu();

            opc = inputNumerico.nextInt();

            switch(opc){


            case 1:
                System.out.println("====== Criar Contato ======\n");
                boolean flag= true; 

                for(int i=0; i<c1.length; i++){
                    if(c1[i]==null){   
                        flag= false; 
                        break;      
                    }
                }



                if(flag==false){
                    Questao5Contato c = new Questao5Contato();

                    c.AdicionarContato(); 

                    for(int i=0; i<c1.length; i++){
                        if(c1[i]==null){ 
                            c1[i]= c; 
                        }

                    }

                    System.out.println("Contato adicionado com sucesso !");
                } else{
                    System.out.println("Lista de contatos cheia !");
                }
                break;


            case 2:
                System.out.println("====== Listar Contato ======");

                int i=0;
                if(c1[i]!=null){
                    c1[i].Listar();

                }   
            }



        }while(opc!=5);
    }

}
```

Comment: A contagem inicia do zero de forma que c1[10] esteja fora do limite

Comment: como eu faço pra resolver isso amigo??

Answer (score 1):

Seu erro está nesta linha:

```
c1[10].Menu();
```

O array `c1` possui tamanho 10, ou seja, suas posições válidas são de 0 a 9, mas você está tentando acessar a décima posição.

Comment: como eu faço pra resolver isso amigo??

Comment: Você se complicou um pouco, porque está querendo chamar o método `Contato.Menu()` sem ter um objeto `Contato`. O que esse método faz? Ele precisa estar dentro da classe `Contato`? Não entendi bem o que você está tentando fazer no seu código.

Comment: Faça o seguinte, [edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/206683/edit) a pergunta e coloque as classes `Contato` e `Questao5Contato`. Mas se quiser uma forma rápida de resolver, dependendo do que o método `Menu()` faz você pode movê-lo para a classe `Questao5Agenda` e declará-lo como `static`.